# Why `if` statement works only after a System.out.println()?

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

I've a class, that contains a `public boolean` variable: `running`. Through a button I can set `running` true or false. In the main class, in the main function I have what follows:

The point is that written in this way the code doesn't work! It works if I add a `System.out.println(frame.running);` before the `if` condition! Do you know why?

I've also tried creating a method, inside the class, `boolean isRunning()` that return a boolean, but it does not work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gui frame = new Gui();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    String received = "";

    while (true) {
        if (frame.running == true) {
            System.out.println(frame.running);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            ricevuti = frame.arduino.receivedstring;
            if (ricevuti.isEmpty()) {
                // do something
            } else {
                int[] intArray = null;
                intArray = frame.arduino.parsing(ricevuti, " ");
                System.out.println(intArray.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(running==true)` is **bad**. Why not just `if(running)` ?

Comment: Have you tested if it checks running faster than you can set it when you start the program? You have no indication to show if the if statement fails?

Comment: As @Hackerdarshi said, you can just use `if(running)`. Also, where are you actually declaring/initializing `running`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `running` as `volatile`. `print` works as work-around because it too forces JVM to synchronize memory.

Anyway, such busy wait loops are not good idea in general,  consider using `wait`-`notify` pattern here.

Comment: whith volatile it works! thank you!

Comment: If that fixed the problem then please mark the answer as "Accepted".